# What does bind(this) is exactly doing in this example of the React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

I'm not quite sure what does `.bind(this)` is exactly doing in this example? Does it simply connect the specified function to the other components of the code such as `this.state`?

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      input: '',
      messages: []
   }
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.submitMessage = this.submitMessage.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: .bind is setting the context for 'this' as an alternative you can use handleChange=()=>{} arrow function which will automatically resolve to use this

Comment: have a look https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a

Comment: Just a side note: You don't need to bind anymore. Instead, you can use class properties with arrow funtcions. like: hanldeChange = (e)=>{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"bind" method is used to pass the context (e.g. "this") to javascript function when it will trigger.

In this case "this" of react component passed to "handleChange" method in the constructor,
so when "handleChange" will invoke, if there is use of "this" inside it code,
"this" will get the  value of parent component.

```
handleCahnge() {
  this.sendSomethingToServer(); // this is react component
}
```

Otherwise, (without using "bind") If some event triggers the function the context 
will be context of event (this will be the event target element instead of conponent)

You can avoid use "bind" syntax is you use arrow function syntax:

handleCange = () => {
     this.sendSomethingToServer()
   };